# Guild lines for working with pre-populated sqlite database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am working on pre-populated sqlite database.
can you please tell which are guide lines for this kind of project.

I am particularity worried about database update.
I have method which copy database form assets folder to data,
if database is not present then it copy database.

My question is, if in next version if I add new table to database then if my old user update their app that time my old database is present in their phone so my new database is not copy.

I search on internet i found there is one method called
onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
can anyone please tell how to use this method, what is oldVersion, newVersion and how this method is work? Is this method add only new tables to old database 
or it replace old database with new one.

In some solution they told to forcefully delete old database and replace it with new one, but is there any way so we only add new table to old database if it present without deleting old database.

if you have any blog link, video tutorial please tell me.

Comment: see [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/)

Comment: Thanks this one looks good